# How do you delete lines in a file when more than one character needs be compared in a file in different lines?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

Eg:

Content of a file xx.txt is:

```
Hi
How Are You Doing
Its Been Long Time
Hope Everything Is Fine
```

So if i need to remove the lines which contain word **Doing** or **Fine**.

The output of the file xx.txt must look like:

```
Hi
Its Been Long Time
```

Is it possible to do this using a single `sed` or `awk` command?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far to solve your problem

Comment: What should happen to a line containing either of the words `Finer` or `Doings`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

To print the output:

```
sed '/Doing\|Fine/d' xx.txt
```

To remove the line directly in a file:

```
sed -i '/Doing\|Fine/d' xx.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked :)

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please consider accepting if (click on the grey check mark below the vote counter) so that others with similar questions may find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -vE "Doing|Fine" xx.txt
```

it will print all the lines which is not having the "Doing and Fine" word

Comment: "Substrings" not "words".  To match words, use `-w` with `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$0 !~/Fine|Doing/' i.txt
```

ouput

```
Hi
Its Been Long Time
```

Comment: As in the other answer Kusalananda pointed out, it will match substring not word.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all lines that has the words `Doing` or `Fine` in them, you may use `grep` in the following manner:

```
grep -Fw -v -e 'Doing' -e 'Fine' file
```

The `-F` option makes `grep` use the given expressions as *strings* rather than as regular expressions, while `-w` makes it match whole words (not substrings of other words, like `Doings` or `Fines`).  The `-v` option inverts the sense of the test so that lines matching the given expressions are removed from the output.  The two strings are given with `-e`, which is used to give the expression to query with (this option is often left out, but is needed here as we have two of them).

---

With `sed`, you could do

```
sed -e '/\<Doing\>/d' -e '/\<Fine\>/d' file
```

or

```
sed '/\<Doing\>/d; /\<Fine\>/d' file
```

or

```
sed -E '/\<(Doing|Fine)\>/d' file
```

Each of of these matches the two string as words.  The `\<` and `\>` special patterns matches the zero-width space at the beginning and end of a word respectively (the space between a word-character and a non-word-character).  With GNU `sed`, you could use `\b` in place of both `\<` and `\>`.

The last `sed` command uses an alternation to match either word.  Alternations is a feature of extended regular expressions, so we enable these using `-E` on the command line.

In all cases, the pattern is matched against every line of input, and if it matches, it is deleted with the `d` command. All other lines are printed.

The inverse, printing all lines that does not match, and ignoring the rest, could be done with

```
sed -n -E '/\<(Doing|Fine)\>/!p' file
```

That is, turn off the default outputting of the data with `-n` and then only print (`p`) the lines that does not match (`!`) the pattern.

---

The `awk` code would look *very similar* to the `sed` code using extended regular expressions, at least if using GNU `awk` (which understands `\<` and `\>`):

```
awk '!/\<(Doing|Fine)\>/' file
```

or

```
awk '!/\<Doing\>/ && !/\<Fine\>/' file
```

These both tries to match the two words against the input data, and would not print the data if the words are present.

You may also use the `index()` function in `awk`, but this would also find the words as substrings (just like using `/(Doing|Fine)/` would do):

```
awk '!index($0, "Doing") && !index($0, "Fine")' file
```

`index($0, string)` returns zero if the `string` is not found in `$0` (the whole line), so negating the result with `!` would give you a *true* value if the string wasn't found.

The long-handed way to do it in `awk` is to check every field separately:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == "Doing" || $i == "Fine") next; print }' file
```

This tests each field against the two words and skips immediately to the next input line if one of them is found.  Otherwise, the line is printed.

This would give different results from using `/\<(Doing|Fine)\>/` if a word like `A-Doing` was present in the text.  The loop would not spot it (because the fields are divided on whitespace), but the regular expression would (because `-` is a non-word-character).